# How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to horizontally center a `<div>` block element on a page and have it set to a minimum width. What is the simplest way to do this? I want the `<div>` element to be inline with rest of my page. I'll try to draw an example:

```
page text page text page text page text
page text page text page text page text
               -------
               | div |
               -------
page text page text page text page text
page text page text page text page text
```

Comment: I don't like any of these answers. What's the solution if you don't know the width? It could just be a single word for example.

Comment: And the point to note is aligning will have no effect if the width is 100%

Comment: I just find out that webgenerator: **http://howtocenterincss.com/**
It does for: you whatever you try to center, however you want it centered. ;)

Comment: Do the this: div.e1{text-align: center;}

Answer (score 824, accepted):

In the case of a **non-fixed width** div (i.e. you don't know how much space the div will occupy).

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: green; /* for visualization purposes */
  text-align: center;
}
#yourdiv {
  background-color: red; /* for visualization purposes */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="yourdiv">Your text</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the width of `#yourdiv` is dynamic -> it will grow and shrink to accommodate the text inside it.

You can check browser compatibility on [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/inline-block)

Comment: I've been using the "margin:0 auto" solution for a long time, but this is better.

Comment: @UriKlar Because margin: 0 auto is easier and more semantically correct.

Comment: This fixed my problem when `margin:0 auto` would not.

Comment: This solution makes inline-block useful!

Comment: if parent div has a float attribute, set child attribute float: none

Comment: This does not actually answer the question, since it asked how to do it with CSS, not with HTML + CSS.

Comment: @NathanHinchey `#wrapper {text-align: center;}` and `#yourdiv {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: The reason I was saying that this requires modifying the HTML isn't because of the inline styling, it was because this assumes you are able to add an additional wrapper div.

Comment: One drawback of this method is that `text-align: center` is inherited, and therefore affects the content, while `margin: 0 auto` doesn't.

Comment: Or I found out that an attribute `align="middle"` works too.
It can be used like this:
`<div align="middle">`
or on image tag
`<img src=".." align="middle">`

Comment: This is a terrible selected solution

Comment: @SamAlexander Care to elaborate why?

Answer (score 578):

In most browsers this will work:

```css
div.centre {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centre">Some Text</div>
```

In IE6 you will need to add another outer `div`:

```css
div.layout {
  text-align: center;
}

div.centre {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="centre">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, due to layout bugs in IE before IE7, you must do this. But in IE8, a simple 

text-align: center

is enough. :)

Comment: That means IE8 is still wrong, as it isn't text.

Comment: The first solution will work in IE6 if it isn't in quirks mode (activated with a comment/standard XML declaration as the first line of your XHTML document).

Comment: I've never actually tried that. So does the browser need to be in strict mode or is it just non-quirks?

Comment: @Antony Scott: It needs to be in strict mode (has any doctype declared).

Comment: I think I'll have a play later on and try that out. Thanks Tom.

Comment: @Antony - Check out http://quirksmode.org/ for browser compatibility info, hacks, workarounds, etc

Comment: Also... only works if you know the width of the container. If the width changes, you have to update your CSS (which stinks if the content is dynamically generated)

Comment: i'm pretty sure it would work if you didn't know the width of your content, but you'd need to setthe width to something as a div will expand to the width of it's container.

Comment: How to do this without setting the width of the div? (The div sizes itself to its content).

Comment: Why do we have to specify width:200px? Why should we hardcode it?

Comment: @BMiner: The fix mentioned for IE6 (an outer container with `text-align: center;`) seems to work for dynamic content.  I'm testing this in Chrome, btw.

Comment: lol - this answer is coming up 6 years old. I have got over IE6, as have most web developers!

Comment: We have got over IE8, so yes

Comment: This works, but it is not ideal. It would be better to use `text-align: center` and `position: relative` on the parent element and then `display: inline-block` on the child element you want to center.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you have to hard code its width.

Comment: @AntonyScott I have tried these styles on a <p> tag and it seems that they only work to center an image.

Answer (score 63):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

as [ck has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css/618104#618104), [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp) is not supported by all browsers

Comment: Note that this only works when the element also has its `width` property set. When you want the element's width to be dynamic (based on its contents), see the chosen answer.

Answer (score 51):

The title of the question and the content is actually different, so I will post two solutions for that using `Flexbox`.

I guess `Flexbox` will replace/add to the current standard solution by the time IE8 and IE9 is completely destroyed ;)

Check the current [**Browser compatibility table for flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

**Single element**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

**Multiple elements but center only one**

Default behaviour is `flex-direction: row` which will align all the child items in a single line. Setting it to `flex-direction: column` will help the lines to be stacked.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.centered {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
   </p>
  <div class="centered"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, Flexbox is the (not so) "modern" way of doing this :)

Comment: Yeah. Care to edit this so that it can reach the general audience, Tivie? ;)

Comment: What do you mean? Your answer works perfectly

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were pointing towards the description being old as I had quit coding for over 2 years and unaware of the current CSS trends. BTW What do you think? Do we need a better system than flexbox for the alignment? Since centering in CSS has been a hot topic for the last 20 years.

Comment: This worked for me when the top two answers didn't. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. It seems we need a major refresh of all our answers.

Comment: @ManojKumar I think flexbox "fixes" a lot of the design issues and is currently supported by almost every browser.

Comment: For some reason margin: 0 auto, didn't work in my Bourbon Neat project, but flexbox saved the day.

Answer (score 35):

If old browsers are not an issue, use HTML5 / CSS3. If they are, apply polyfills and still use HTML5 / CSS3. I assume that your div has no margins or paddings here, but they are relatively easy to account for. The code follows.

```
.centered {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

What this does is:

1. Position the `div` relative to its container;
2. Position the `div`'s left boundary at 50% of **its container width** horizontally;
3. Translate back horizontally by 50% of **the `div`'s own width**.

It is easy to imagine this process to confirm that the `div` would be horizontally centered eventually. As a bonus, you can **center vertically** at no additional cost:

```
.centered-vertically {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to do any counterintuitive stuff, such as considering your div a text of sorts, wrapping it in a (often semantically useless) additional container, or giving it a fixed width, which is not always possible.

Don't forget vendor prefixes for `transform` if needed.

Comment: An issue with the horizontal method is that the centered element will not dynamically scale past 50% of the parent's width: https://jsfiddle.net/ywy9w3gk/

Answer (score 30):

```css
.center {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Minimum width is not globally supported, but can be implemented using

```css
.divclass {
   min-width: 200px;
}
```

Then you can set your div to be

```html
<div class="center divclass">stuff in here</div>
```

Answer (score 28):

**CSS**, **HTML**:

```css
div.mydiv {width: 200px; margin: 0 auto}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    
    I am in the middle
    
</div>
```

Your diagram shows a block level element also (which a div usually is), not an inline one.

Of the top of my head, `min-width` is supported in FF2+/Safari3+/IE7+. Can be done for IE6 using hackety CSS, or a simple bit of JS.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the "inline" terminology. I was trying to say that I didn't want it to float over any text.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `position: relative` and `text-align: center` on the parent element and then `display: inline-block` on the child element you want to center. This is a simple CSS design pattern that will work across all major browsers. Here is an example below or check out the [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/joshuapekera/pen/ZGJzYo).

```css
p {
  text-align: left;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Style your object */

.object {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #556270;
}
.centerthis {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p>Aeroplanigera Mi Psychopathologia Subdistinctio Chirographum Intuor Sons Superbiloquentia Os Sors Sesquiseptimus Municipatio Archipresbyteratus O Conclusio Compedagogius An Maius Septentrionarius Plas Inproportionabilit Constantinopolis Particularisticus.</p>

  <span class="object centerthis">Something Centered</span>

  <p>Aeroplanigera Mi Psychopathologia Subdistinctio Chirographum Intuor Sons Superbiloquentia Os Sors Sesquiseptimus Municipatio Archipresbyteratus O Conclusio Compedagogius.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-align: center` did the trick. Just needed to add that to the parent element.

Answer (score 10):

Please use the below code and your div will be in the center.

```
.class-name {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use `margin: 0 auto` on your css instead of `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 8):

If you know the width of your div and it is fixed, you can use the following css:

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 'half-of-your-div-width');
```

where 'half-of-your-div-width' should be (obviously) the half of the width of your div.

Answer (score 5):

Add this class to your css file it will work perfectly 
steps to do:

1) create this first

```
<div class="center-role-form">
  <!--your div (contrent) place here-->
</div>
```

2) add this to your css

```
.center-role-form {
    width: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After nine years I thought it was time to bring a new version. Here are my two (and now one) favourites.

**Margin**

Set `margin` to `auto`. You should know the direction sequence is `margin: *top* *right* *bottom* *left*;` or `margin: *top&bottom* *left&right*`

```css
aside{
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

article{
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px; /* 50px aside width */
    background-color: grey;
}

div{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside>
        </aside>
        <article>           
                <div>The div</div>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Center: Depricated, don't use this!**

Use `<center></center>` tags as a wrap around your `<div></div>`.

Example:

```css
aside{
    display:block;
    background-color:green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}

center{
    display:block;
    background-color:grey;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px; /* Width of the aside */
}

div{
    display:block; 
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px; 
    background-color:blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside>
        </aside>
        <article>
            <center>
                <div>The div</div>
            </center>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.center {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center>div {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div>You text</div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e74pajk/)

Comment: This did the trick for me, specifically helps center the whole div not just the text inside of it.

Answer (score 3):

If your `<div>` has `position: absolute` you need to use `width: 100%;`

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

    #child {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I add proper answer

You can use this snippet code and customize. Here I use 2 child block.This should show center of the page.
You can use one or multiple blocks.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 35px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="mydiv" id="parent">


<div class="child">
Block 1
</div>
<div class="child">
Block 2
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best response to this question is to use `margin-auto` but for using it you must know the `width` of your `div` in `px` or `%`.

CSS code:

```
div{
    width:30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`, you might want to write `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 1):

In your html file you write:

```
<div class="banner">
  Center content
</div>
```

your css file you write:

```
.banner {
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
}
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto may not work in certain situations. Here is a solution what will always work. You specify a required width and than set a left-margin to a half of the remaining width.

```
    <div style="width:80%; margin-left:calc(10%);">
        your_html
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use div and span tags together with css properties such as block, cross-browser inline-block and text-align center, see my simple example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
       <style>
           .block{display:block;}
           .text-center{text-align:center;}
           .border-dashed-black{border:1px dashed black;}
           .inline-block{
                 display: -moz-inline-stack;
                 display: inline-block;
                 zoom: 1;
                 *display: inline;
            }
           .border-solid-black{border:1px solid black;}
           .text-left{text-align:left;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class="block text-center border-dashed-black">
              <span class="block text-center">
                  <span class="block"> 
        <!-- The Div we want to center set any width as long as it is not more than the container-->
                      <div class="inline-block text-left border-solid-black" style="width:450px !important;">
                             jjjjjk
                      </div> 
                  </span>
              </span>
          </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myElement").wrap( '<span class="myElement_container_new"></span>' ); // for IE6
    $(".myElement_container_new").css({// for IE6
        "display" : "block",
        "position" : "relative",
        "margin" : "0",
        "padding" : "0",
        "border" : "none",
        "background-color" : "transparent",
        "clear" : "both",
        "text-align" : "center"
    });
    $(".myElement").css({
        "display" : "block",
        "position" : "relative",
        "max-width" : "75%", // for example
        "margin-left" : "auto",
        "margin-right" : "auto",
        "clear" : "both",
        "text-align" : "left"
    });
});
```

or, if you want to center every element with class ".myElement":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myElement").each(function() {
        $(this).wrap( '<span class="myElement_container_new"></span>' ); // for IE6
        $(".myElement_container_new").css({// for IE6
            "display" : "block",
            "position" : "relative",
            "margin" : "0",
            "padding" : "0",
            "border" : "none",
            "background-color" : "transparent",
            "clear" : "both",
            "text-align" : "center"
        });
        $(this).css({
            "display" : "block",
            "position" : "relative",
            "max-width" : "75%",
            "margin-left" : "auto",
            "margin-right" : "auto",
            "clear" : "both",
            "text-align" : "left"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use the position:relative; and then set the left and the top values:

```
.cenverDiv{
    position:relative;
    left:30%;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: That's not really easy though, it requires a lot of experimentation to get the values right.

Comment: That's not really useful.