# How do I center this form in css?

Tags: css

I have tried everything.  I cannot get this centered on the screen.  I am using ie 9 but it does the same in chrome.  It just sits on the left of the webpage.  Thank you for any help.

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    align:center;
}
label,input {
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
 text-align: right;
 width: 75px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

br {
 clear: left;
}



    </style>
</head>


<body>

 <form name="Form1"  action="mypage.asp" method="get">

 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <input id="name" name="name"><br>

 <label for="address">Address</label>
 <input id="address" name="address"><br>

 <label for="city">City</label>
 <input id="city" name="city"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="button" />

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Another way

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="abc">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: doesn't work, text-align: center applies to all children of the form, not the form itself

Comment: I get same results as @CoryDanielson in Chrome 25; form *content* is centered.

Comment: I'm late, but you can wrap the form in a div and move `text-align: center;` to that parent div to have the entire form centered, not just the contents.

Comment: The `text-align` has to be on the parent of the form.

Comment: @CoryDanielson, try:  `form { display: inline-block; text-align: left; }`

Answer (score 49):

1. Wrap your form in a div.
2. Set the div's display to block and text-align to center (this will center the contained form).
3. Set the form's display to inline-block (auto-sizes to content), left and right margins to auto (centers it horizontally), and text-align to left (or else its children will be center-aligned too).

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <form name="Form1" action="mypage.asp" method="get">
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.form
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
form
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
body { text-align: center; }
     /* center all items within body, this property is inherited */
body > * { text-align: left; }
     /* left-align the CONTENTS all items within body, additionally
        you can add this text-align: left property to all elements
        manually */
form { display: inline-block; }
     /* reduces the width of the form to only what is necessary */
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/sqdBr/4/

Works & tested in Chrome/IE/FF

Answer (score 19):

You can try

```
form {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Or

```
form {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: that will only move the form from the left by 25%.. unless the form is very wide, it will never be affected by margin-right: 25%, and width: 100% is default

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this to your css

```
.form { width:985px; margin:0 auto }
```

and add width:100% to the body tag

Then put:

```
<div class="form">
```

before the  tag.

Comment: What is 985px? How did you come up with that number?

Comment: Sorry 985px would be the form width. That was just an example. You can change that width to whatever you like :)

Comment: Just make sure you have a defined width. The auto margins used to center will only work with a defined width in there.

Comment: hardcoding widths is a dieing trend, you can just do `display: inline-block;` on the form itself, then center-align that

Comment: I have never known it to be a "dieing trend". I would call it a realiable trend, it works on all browsers and has done for years. With your suggestion you need to continuously set your text-align back to left for other elements which is more hassle

Comment: a fixed width isn't very flexible/liquid
`body { text-align: left; }` and then `body > * { text-align: left; }` is pretty simple...

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code for your 'body' tag, change it as you like..

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Idk what was wrong with my template, but this was the only answer that worked for me. No reason to force that margin-top though.  Suggest that be removed from this answer.

Answer (score 3):

i dont know if the full resolution has been made for this yet. i know that from doing a 2 column page with fixed left side bar, to get a contact us form centered on my page i put the following:

```
    form {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

this worked for me so thought id throw in my resolution to the same problem

Answer (score 3):

This best solution I found online is using absolute positioning.

```
.login-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-49%, -49%);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS to center the form (note that it is important to set the width to something that isn´t 'auto' for this to work):

```
form {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   width:100px;
}
```

Comment: The width cannot be auto. This will align it to the left in some browsers (definitely FF)

Answer (score 1):

I css I got no idea
but I made that just by centering the form in html
something like this:

in css:

```
form.principal {width:12em;}    
form.principal label { float:left; display:block; clear:both; padding:3px;}
form.principal input { float:left; width:8em;}
form.principal button{clear:both; width:130px; height:50px; margin-top:8px;}
```

then in html:

```
<center><form class="principal" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<p><label for="username">User</label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
<p><label for="password">Password</label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" /></p>
<button>Log in</button>
</fieldset>
</form></center>
```

This will center the form, and the content will be in the left of the centered form.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you look up any software issue on stackoverflow, you quickly find a clear answer. But in CSS, even something as simple as "center a form" leads to a long discussion, and lots of failed solutions.

Correction: orfdorf's solution (above) works.

Comment: This may be better suited to a comment on the actual answer, than a brand new answer

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
form {
    width:90%;
    background-color: #c0d7f8;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="abc">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Private</title>

    <!-- local links -->
<style>


body{
    background-color:#6e6969;
    text-align:center;
}
body .form_wrapper{

    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px 18px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "form_wrapper">
        <form method="post" action="function.php">
            <h1 class = "formHeading">Admin login form</h1>
            <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username"placeholder = "Enter Username" required = "required">
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id  = "password" placeholder = "Enter password" required = "required">
            <button type = "submit" >Login</button>
            <a href = "#"> froget password!</a>
            <a href = "#"><span>?</span>help</a>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (without a wrapper) would be to set the form to `display: table`, which would make it act like a table so it would have the width of its largest child, and then apply `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

```
form {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378738/7841955

Answer (score 1):

```
form {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (i use google)
What i did is i added the align attribute to the form

```
<form align="center">
   <!--Stuff-->
</form>
```

That is one solution

Comment: Original poster requested CSS solution

Comment: Yes, but it is "sort of" CSS enough.  I gave an upvote for trying and because you are a New Contributor.  Thanks Ebrahim.  No offense Don.

Comment: Inline CSS should be avoided as much as possible.