# CSS: HTML align form center, but having Labels and Legend aligned in the Left

Tags: css

For a HTML code (here based on Thymeleaf)

```html
 <body>
        <form th:object="${book}">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Book</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="id">Id:</label></td>
                    <td><input th:id="id"
                               th:readonly="readonly"
                               th:size="50"
                               th:type="text"
                               th:value="*{id}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="title">Title:</label></td>
                    <td><input th:id="title"
                               th:readonly="readonly"
                               th:size="50"
                               th:type="text"
                               th:value="*{title}"></td>
                </tr>
```

I found this post:

- [How do I center this form in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097744/how-do-i-center-this-form-in-css)

Thus is used:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here the purpose is have the form in the center of the page:

The result is:

[image]

Until here works as expected until some point.

But what is the CSS extra code required to:

- have the Labels located in the left (right now is centered).
- have the Legend located in the left (right now is centered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution for your scenario:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```