# Center a div, as width as its content

Tags: html, css

I want to center a DIV which width is unknown. It should be as width as the actual content. I tried:

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 300px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">dsffsffsfsddf</div>
```

it only works when "width" is set. `Auto` wont help.

Comment: I don't understand. If the width is unknown, then being a block element the width is 100% and centering is irrelevant. If the width is being set somehow, then `margin:0 auto` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: table; margin: 0 auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/vabxz/

Comment: Please provide a little more context for the person who asked.

Comment: Works in all browsers except ≤ IE7, so it should be good. But if you need IE7 then the only way is http://jsfiddle.net/w6UcB/ like JasonB mentioned, but it requires extra markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
div{
    display:table
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this previous answer: [centering variable width divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266755/easy-way-to-center-variable-width-divs-in-css)

But one answer is to basically use css-floats

```
<style type="text/css">
#hideoverflow { overflow: hidden; }
#outer { position: relative; left: 50%; float: left; }
#inner { position: relative; left: -50%; float: left; }
</style>

<div id="hideoverflow">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id velit vel  augue fringilla rhoncus at et odio. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam justo  libero, commodo ut iaculis in, placerat vel purus.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As Xeepete points out, this is the belt and braces approach for browsers down to IE7. If you don't need to go that far, use the display : table; as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple (http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/tYyJN/):

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #f00; display:inline-block;">some content</div>
</div>
```

The key points are `text-align:center` for the outer box and `display:inline-block` for the inner box

Answer (score 1):

**Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRUBd/**

CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   This div is as wide as its content and centered!
</div>
```

[image]