# How to center a DIV with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to center a `div` with CSS. I googled some stuff & checked on stackoverflow but it was conflicting with my CSS code.

Here's my code (just in case):

```css
body, p, span, div  {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', arial, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#6d6d6d; } 
.countdown { 
    padding-top:15px; width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.countdown .countdown_section{
    background:url('images/backcountdown.png') no-repeat 1px top;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:54px;
    margin:0 5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:6px;
}
.countdown .countdown_amount { 
    font-size:15px;
    color:#ab7100; 
    text-shadow:0 0.8px #fedd98; 
    line-height:52px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-align: left; 
}
.countdown span { 
    font-size:8px;
    color:#999999;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:26px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="countdown clearfix">       
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What did you find? Conflicting how? Your CSS is a pain to read too.

Comment: can you provide us with the HTML in question, there are some fairly common ways to center a div, but what are we centering it in? are you supporting versions of IE prior to 9?

Comment: Next time I'll write all the codes vertically instead of horizontally :P.

Comment: I'm supporting versions from IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can center a div with a specific width using the following css:

```
#yourDiv {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The following automatically centers the element horizontally:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: What I want to center is .countdown which already has margin:0 auto 0 auto. & If I have kept it like that to have a sticky footer. Is there any otherways ?

Comment: You've specified `width: 100%` for `.countdown`, so the div will use the whole width, how should it be centered then? Or do you want to center the text inside?

Comment: The width must be less than the parent container's width. If it is set to 100% then it can't be centered.

Comment: I think this should have been marked as the correct answer, as this answers the question of the OP (he asked how to center "a div" - he didn't say he had trouble because of the width nor did he specify a specific div. Also, this post was a *bit* earlier (well.. 1 minute)

Answer (score 3):

Provided fixed width is set, and you put a proper DOCTYPE,

Do this:

```
 Margin-left: auto;
 Margin-right: auto;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

To center a div use:

```
#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="content">This will be centered horizontally</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="margin:auto; width: 100px;">lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers will work for divs with relative or static positioning. For absolutely positioned elements (like your `.countdown` element, you'll need to set `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -XXXpx` where `XXX` represents half of the div's width (including padding and border).

(example: http://jsfiddle.net/7dhwG/)

Comment: Tried it but got a horizontal scrollbar. Still np, Thanks a lot !.

Comment: You'll need to specify an explicit width in pixels for `.countdown` of something less than 100% of its parent's width.

Answer (score 2):

This will center your page it works great.

```
  #yourdiv {
  width: width you want px;
  margin: 0 auto;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also center an absolute position div by setting left to 50% and margin-left to -half of the full width in px.

```
div {
 position: absolute;
 width: 500px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -251px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using margin: 0 auto, Cross browser way of doing this is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css/43509117#43509117) I have tested it and it works perfectly on all browsers