# CSS How to center a div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am working on centering a div horizontally. I have the following code to center my div in the body tag both vertically and horizontally, but seems just the vertical piece works. How can I get the horizontal piece to work as well. Thanks in advance.

```
body
{
    background-color: #081418;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969; 
    text-align: center;
}

.OuterRim
{
    border:5px solid #99D7C0;
    height: 97%;
    width: 85%;
    /*center aligning*/ 
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px auto;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css

Comment: Nope. That link does not help at all. If you look closely you will see I already applied the answers from that example and still not getting the desired result.

Comment: see my answer on this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css/43509117#43509117)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take [a look here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/)  at this tutorial to learn how to do it. You need to have an element with a fixed width. This can be done with css or jquery.

Comment: Whats here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp seems more simple, that is what I used. Thanks for the link, wasn't aware of such a site, the jquery book is very useful :)

Comment: You should always include the informations from the linked article in your post in case the link dies.

Answer (score 6):

```
margin:0px auto;
```

if the div is positioned absolute or fixed then use

```
margin:0px auto;
left:0;
right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/jm7vF/1/

I believe this may solve your problem if I understand it correctly.

I placed a container div around your div and put percentage margins all around.

```
.container {
height: 50%;
margin: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
```

Hope this helps!