# Centering divs without increasing their size & keeping the header together with the text?

Tags: html, css, layout

I realize that I am asking two separate questions here, but given my inexperience with HTML and CSS, I get the feeling that they are connected. If nothing else, I am unsure about how to ask one question while ensuring that the answers I get will be compatible with the other.

So, here goes:

I am making a small calculator, which needs to look nice in different window sizes. I have some groupings of buttons that all need to be kept together, while the different groupings are moved around according to the window size. Below is a screenshot of "good behavior":

[image: Screenshot 1]

The content is together with headers, and there are no odd blank spaces.

Then we get the next behavior: upon a small change of window width, some material is moved down, but not the entire div - the header stays:

[image: Screenshot 2]

How do I make the header follow the content down?

Finally, when the window width gets even smaller, the header moves down as well:

[image]

This behavior is fine but I'd like the remaining content in the top to take advantage of the extra space and center horizontally. Any idea how? I've had a look at questions such as [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css), but they all seem to entail increasing the width of the element that I want centered, which breaks the behavior in screenshot #1.

An example of that is seen here:

[image: screenshot 4]

How do I fix screenshots #2 and #3, without affecting #1?

I have of course also made a fiddle, but I thought screenshots would make the point better:

http://jsfiddle.net/eEPmw/

in it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .incbut,.decbut,.rollButton{
        background-color:#FF961F;
      }
      .regular-checkbox{
        border-color:#FF961F;
      }

      body {
        background-color:#FCB41B;
        color:#753B08;
      }

      .modifiers{
        text-align:left;
        min-width:8em;
      }
      .center{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
      }
      .inputField {
        max-width:2em;
        border:1px #bababa solid;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
      }
      .incbut,.decbut {
        border: 1px transparent solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        position: relative;
        width: 2.5em;
      }
      .rollButton{
        border: 1px transparent solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        position: relative;#FF0000
      }
      button:active{
        background-color:#FF0000;
      }
      .fieldCol{
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
        max-width=45%;
        height:9em;
      }
      input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
      input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .incbut,.inputField, .decbut{
        min-height:2em;
        margin-right:0.5em; 
        margin-bottom:0.3em; 
      }
      h2{
        margin:0.1em;
        font-weight:500;
      }
      h2,button, input{
        font-family:inherit;
      }
      .outputField{
        padding:2px;
        margin:3px;
        border:1px #753B08 solid;
        width=2em;
        line-height:1.7em;
        white-space:nowrap; 
      }
      label {
        display: inline;
      }
      .checkBoxLabel{
        margin-left:5px;
        font-size:90%;
      }
      .regular-checkbox {
        display: none;
      }
      .regular-checkbox + label {
        border: 3px solid #FF961F;
        padding: 9px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative; 
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin: .1em;
      }
      .regular-checkbox:checked + label {
      border: 3px solid #FF961F;
      }
      .regular-checkbox:checked + label:after {
        content: '\2716';
        font-size: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 10%;
        color: #753B08;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      .checkboxbox2{
        width:8em;
        float:left;
      }
      .colContainer{
        text-alignment:center;
      }
      div.centre{
        text-align: left;
        width: 17em;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center;font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="center">      


<!--
<div class="colContainer">
<div class="centre">
-->
  <section id="bal_attacker" class="fieldCol">
    <h2>Attacker:</h2>
    <label for="bal_BS1">BS:</label> <br>
    <button type="button" id="bal_BS1inc" class="incbut"> + </button> 
    <input type="number" id="bal_BS1" value="1" class="inputField"> 
    <button type="button" id="bal_BS1dec" class="decbut"> - </button> <br> 
    <label for="bal_S">S:</label> <br>
    <button type="button" id="bal_Sinc" class="incbut"> + </button> 
    <input type="number" id="bal_S" value="1" class="inputField"/>
    <button type="button" id="bal_Sdec" class="decbut"> - </button> 
  </section>
  <section id="bal_defender" class="fieldCol" >
    <h2>Defender:</h2>
    <label for="bal_T">T:</label> <br>
    <button type="button" id="bal_Tinc" class="incbut"> + </button> 
    <input type="number" id="bal_T" value="1" class="inputField"> 
    <button type="button" id="bal_Tdec" class="decbut"> - </button>  <br> 
  </section>

<!--
</div>
</div>

-->
  <div>

  <section title="bal_Modifiers" class="modifiers">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Modifiers:</h2><br>
    <span class="checkboxbox2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="bal_harmConv" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="bal_harmConv"></label>
      <label for="bal_harmConv" class="checkBoxLabel">Harm. Conv.</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkboxbox2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="bal_rrToHit" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="bal_rrToHit"></label>
      <label for="bal_rrToHit" class="checkBoxLabel">R.r. to hit</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkboxbox2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="bal_rrToW" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="bal_rrToW"></label>
      <label for="bal_rrToW" class="checkBoxLabel">R.r. to wound</label>
    </span>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </section>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I apologize that this is not quite a minimal working example - I have been trying for some time now to reduce it further, but I seem to break stuff when I try.

Comment: you need to make a 3 column layout, `col1 = attacker`, `col2 = defender`, `col3= modifiers`. That will insure that when the screen shrinks past a point all elements in that column will drop. Next you need to use percentages within your columns to allow for even distribution of the elements within, or give each col a fixed with and all the widths of the elements inside relevant to the with of the parent column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix:

Put everything in a holder div ("wrap", some call it):

```
<div id="holder">
   <section> .... </section>
   <section> .... </section>
   <section> .... </section>
</div>
```

Then make the holder `text-align:center;` and the sections `display:inline-block;`, and likely you'll want `vertical-align:top;`.

```
#holder{
   text-align:center;
}
section{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

From your jsFidle, you'll also want to remove `float:left;` from `.fieldCol`

[Here's your jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/eEPmw/1/)

Comment: this solves the centering, but it seems to have the same problem with non-optimal packing as shown in screenshot #4?

Comment: Glad to help! `display:inline-block` is not very well supported (cough..IE) If you'd like to make this work cross-browser, be sure to check out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: "display:inline-block is not very well supported" <- why do people keep saying this nonsense?  IE6 is pretty much dead in the water now and IE7 is not far behind.

Comment: Fair point. I guess I'm just re-iterating information from several years ago. [This browser support chart shows which browsers support it (most all do)](http://caniuse.com/inline-block). and [StatCounter shows that IE7 now falls under "other"](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201209-201302-bar), so it's really not much of a concern

Comment: hmm, is there a way to make the "modifiers" section switch between column and row layout depending on whether it has the room for a row? that was the strength of the float:left-solution, the vertical dimension was minimized as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create this layout with the responsiveness you've specified, Flexbox is what you're looking for.  I've simplified the markup a bit:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/djwsz

```
<div id="calculator">
    <section id="bal_attacker" class="fieldCol">
        <h2>Attacker:</h2>

        <div>
            <label for="bal_BS1">BS:</label> <br>
            <button type="button" id="bal_BS1inc" class="incbut"> + </button> 
            <input type="number" id="bal_BS1" value="1" class="inputField"> 
            <button type="button" id="bal_BS1dec" class="decbut"> - </button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="bal_S">S:</label> <br>
            <button type="button" id="bal_Sinc" class="incbut"> + </button> 
            <input type="number" id="bal_S" value="1" class="inputField"/>
            <button type="button" id="bal_Sdec" class="decbut"> - </button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="bal_defender" class="fieldCol" >
        <h2>Defender:</h2>

        <div>
            <label for="bal_T">T:</label> <br>
            <button type="button" id="bal_Tinc" class="incbut"> + </button> 
            <input type="number" id="bal_T" value="1" class="inputField"> 
            <button type="button" id="bal_Tdec" class="decbut"> - </button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section title="bal_Modifiers" class="modifiers">
        <h2>Modifiers:</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="bal_harmConv" class="regular-checkbox" /> Harm. Conv.</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="bal_rrToHit" class="regular-checkbox" /> R.r. to hit</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="bal_rrToW" class="regular-checkbox" /> R.r. to wound</label></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

These should be all of the styles you need, I've chopped out all of the purely aesthetic styles that aren't really relevant to the layout (colors, padding, etc.):

```
#calculator, section.modifiers ul {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  #calculator, section.modifiers ul {
    display: flex;
  }
}

#calculator section {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 30%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 30%;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}

section.modifiers ul {
  padding: 0;
}

section.modifiers li {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 33%;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 33%;
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Now the bad news is that support for Flexbox is rather poor at the moment.  Right now, only Opera, Chrome, and IE10 are capable of rendering this layout.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: actually, that's not necessarily a deal-breaker, though a pity none the less.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can still combine it with inline-block as a fallback for old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the headers in parent divs along with the elements you want them to stay with.

```
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="content">
        //Whatever your content is
    </div>
</div>
```

As for centering, `margin: 0 auto;` is what's typically done for this, but since you're going to have a float, you're probably going to have to write some script to handle that for you based on `.length()` of the parent divs and the width of the grandparent container.

Comment: actually, the header is already in a section together with the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick mock can use to get started.

> you need to make a 3 column layout, col1 = attacker, col2 = defender,
>   col3= modifiers. That will insure that when the screen shrinks past a
>   point all elements in that column will drop. Next you need to use
>   percentages within your columns to allow for even distribution of the
>   elements within, or give each col a fixed with and all the widths of
>   the elements inside relevant to the with of the parent column.

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bRRqW/**

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col">
        <h4>Attacker:</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dignissimos voluptatem in ut minima doloremque fuga qui saepe! Esse laudantium non voluptates deleniti soluta ab praesentium velit id omnis corrupti.</p>
    </div>
    <div c**strong text**lass="col">
        <h4>Defender:</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dignissimos voluptatem in ut minima doloremque fuga qui saepe! Esse laudantium non voluptates deleniti soluta ab praesentium velit id omnis corrupti.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h4>Modifier:</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dignissimos voluptatem in ut minima doloremque fuga qui saepe! Esse laudantium non voluptates deleniti soluta ab praesentium velit id omnis corrupti.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 600px;   
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col { 
    width: 33.333333%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 150px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that the columns are not in fact centering when the screen-size is changed?