# css center horizontally

Tags: css

i have a problem using css.

```
.ventabotones div{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

.ventabotones{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ventabotones{
    height:80px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

How could center horizontally #ventabotones content?

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css

Comment: Your css says ventabotones is a class, while you say it's an id... Center aligning a div (or mostly the whole body in my case) I mostly do with `margin: 0 auto 0;`

Comment: I strongly recommend to use as little code blocks as necessary. So put `overflow: hidden` into the other `.ventabotones` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in css div you want to center on paginal

```
margin : 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your css.

```
.ventabotones{
  text-align:center;
}
```

and if it still doesn't come in center, possible reasons

- your container doesn't have enough width to show the content in center
- some global CSS Class is overriding the local CSS Class

that's all that can be said without a glimpse of your html markup