# Center a DIV to the center of page regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to center the below div container to that the site appears in the center of the page, regardless of the screen size.

http://penarthpc.com/~droneboy/

I've played around a little bit but appear to be missing something.

Comment: _regardless of the screen size_ If it includes mobile phones also, use **Media Queries**.

Comment: Post some HTML/CSS or else no one knows what the problem is...

Comment: look at this : http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/css-tips-how-to-center-an-element/

Answer (score 14):

The solution to this problem is using `auto` for `margin` in the CSS AND providing some width to the DIV itself:

```
div.centered {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to center something regardless of page width is `margin: auto;` in your CSS, with height and width defined.

```
.class {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rVXBH/

Answer (score 4):

```
.center-div {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -300px;
   margin-top: -300px;
}
```

This will center your DIV with class `center-div` horizontally AND vertically. The `margin-left` must be negative half of what your width is. The `margin-top` must be negative half the height.

To just center horizontally:

```
.center-div {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

simple. Just give the container margin of "0 auto"

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to center the container (vertical) :

[vertical centering with css](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

if (horizontal) look at this :

[how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work for any screen size.

```css
div.centered {
   background-color: rgb(18, 80, 144);
   height: 100vh;
}
div.centered span {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   color: rgb(250, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
 <span>Center</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the content in the div is an image? How then would it be centered?

Comment: based on the image size reduce left percentage.

Comment: I have updated the CSS to fit for both image and text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great method I use, it makes use of a *before* selector to create a invisible div that takes care of the vertical alignment:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="outter-div">
        <div id="aligned">
            <h1>A Nice Title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
#outter-div {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
#outter-div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */
#aligned{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

This can be found on [this post](http://www.flaviodiez.com/2013/07/vertical-horizontal-alignment/) which also has a demo on jsbin!

Answer (score 0):

CSS below to center any element :

```
div.className {

text-align: center;

}
```