# What will be CSS snippet to make center position for child div into a parent div --

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need the exact CSS snippet to making center position for child div into a parent div.

Comment: I wrote its answer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css/30109735#30109735

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, without the need to know the dimensions of either div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered">
         [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;

    // Center upper left corner
    // Percentage is relative to width/height of parent container
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    // Move centered element so its center is centered
    // Percentage is relative to width/height of centered element
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```