# How to center align this form on my website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been having issues center aligning the contents of a div in a wordpress site I made. The site is http://www.triplebs.ca and I want the "subscribe to our newsletter" div to have everything in it centered, but can't figure it out. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Can you copy/paste some code?

Comment: Try `.newsletter-widget, .et_pb_widget {text-align:center}`

Comment: You need to post relevant code here. The reason why is to help others with the same problem that you have. If the URL that you have posted is 404'ed you can't help anybody and the question is useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.newsletter-widget, .widget_newsletterwidget {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS rules:

```
.newsletter-widget p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also you need to add to the closest `form` tag:

```
text-align: center;
```