# How to center align div using css3?

Tags: css, alignment

I am new to `css3`. Just wanted to know how to center align a div, it should work on web browser, web-kit. I don't have the exact size of the page. I tried

```
div.inputs { 
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

But this never works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Horizontally & Vertically:**

**Stable Solution (supports flexible height easily):**

A more stable code could be look like this which works for vertically & horizontally center a fixed-width, flexible height content:

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px
  /*whatever width you want*/
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">

      <h1>The Content</h1>

      <p>The inner content :)</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Quick and dirty:**

According to your comment on another answer you want it to be centered horizontally and vertically or only horizontally. You can do this by using position absolute:

```css
.centerDiv {
    width:270px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
    
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerDiv">Center Me :)</div>
```

---

## **Only horizontally:**

If you want it to be centered only horizontally simply use:

```
.centerDiv {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: perfect @DominikAngerer

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your HTML you could use `display: flex` to achieve an easy completely centred element with a small amount of CSS and no additional HTML elements

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Here is an example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuy3cr3t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to define the width, and then set margin to auto & 0:

```
div.inputs{ margin: 0 auto; width 100%}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cb20q16n/1/)**

Comment: even after having a width the div still remains at the top. is it because it is nested under two divs and that is causing the issue?

Comment: @chetank your comment "remains at the top" makes it sound like you want to VERTICALLY align, even though your example is referencing horizontal alignment...

Comment: @ganders i want the div to be centered, horizontally or vertically. I am not sure what might be the condition but my html is comething like this                                         <div id="content"><section><div claSS=INPUTS></div></section></div>

Comment: if you don't know which you want... how can we answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the size of your element, you can use the `display: inline-block;` with a parent having `text-align: center;` or you can use a `display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css/43509117#43509117) here I used just div and span tag to center a div