# Div isn't responsive while scaling up

Tags: html, css

My problem is that in mobile view which is 320px wide, everything looks okay, but when I start manually scaling up, the nav won't stay in center. It just stays on the left side of the screen, when the right side gets bigger. Title (h1) scales up normally. Navigation "buttons" should remain with the same width till break which is 768px wide.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #626262;
}
/*** NAVIGATION ***/

.main-nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #626262;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: .75em;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.profile-icon {
  height: 125px;
  width: 200px;
}
/******  PORTFOLIO    ********/

.main-content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Title1</h1>

    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <img src="images/responsive-layout-profile.png" class="profile-icon">

    <p>Text field</p>

  </div>
</header>
<div class="main-content">
  <h2 class="title-two">PORTFOLIO</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal, verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post

Comment: this looks like what you are looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13k5k33c/2/)**

you were using both `display:flex` and `display:inline-block` on `li a` . just use one `display` .

i suggest you don't use fixed width on the buttons, but instead use `float:left` with `percentage`

also you say that you want the buttons to remain the same width till 768px, but you set a width of `width: 280px * 3 = 840px`. so ofcourse the three buttons don't fit on 768px device width.

added also a media Q for below 768px

check also snippet

```css
body {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font-family: helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.main-nav {
  padding:0;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #626262;
}

/*** NAVIGATION ***/

.main-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
     width: 32.66%;
     margin-right:1%;
}

ul li:last-child { margin-right:0;}
.main-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #626262;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: .75em;
    display:block;
   
    

    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}

.profile-icon {
    height: 125px;
    width: 200px;


}





 /******  PORTFOLIO    ********/

.main-content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  .main-nav li { width:100%}
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
     <h1 class="title">Title1</h1>

     <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img src="images/responsive-layout-profile.png" class="profile-icon">

    <p>Text field</p>

   </div>
 </header>
    <div class="main-content">
       <h2 class="title-two">PORTFOLIO</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13k5k33c/3/)**

you were using both `display:flex` and `display:inline-block` on `li a` . just use one `display` .

i suggest you don't use fixed width on the buttons, but instead use `float:left` with `percentage`

also you say that you want the buttons to remain the same width till 768px, but you set a width of `width: 280px * 3 = 840px`. so ofcourse the three buttons don't fit on 768px device width.

added also a media Q for below 768px

check also snippet

```css
body {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font-family: helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.main-nav {
  padding:0;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #626262;
}

/*** NAVIGATION ***/

.main-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
     width: 32.66%;
     margin-right:1%;
}

ul li:last-child { margin-right:0;}
.main-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #626262;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: .75em;
    display:block;
   
    

    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}

.profile-icon {
    height: 125px;
    width: 200px;


}





 /******  PORTFOLIO    ********/

.main-content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  .main-nav li { width:100%;margin:0}
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
     <h1 class="title">Title1</h1>

     <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <img src="images/responsive-layout-profile.png" class="profile-icon">

    <p>Text field</p>

   </div>
 </header>
    <div class="main-content">
       <h2 class="title-two">PORTFOLIO</h2>
    </div>
```