# Horizontally center a div at the top of the page

Tags: html, css

How can I center the text in the div vertically and how can I center the div across the width of the screen by placing it at the top?

https://jsfiddle.net/gL320uLr/

```
<div id='custom'>
  textfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
</div> 

#custom{
 width: 50%;
 background: #FF0000;
 z-index: 99999;
 transform-origin: center center;
 position: absolute; 
 left:50%;
 top: 10px; 
 margin:0 auto;
 height: 52px;
 border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: no, I need center only horizontally, in the top the page..

Comment: "How can I center the text in the div vertically" ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you want

```css
#custom {
  width: 50%;
  background: #FF0000;
  z-index: 99999;
  transform-origin: center center;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*-----*/
  line-height: 52px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='custom'>
  textfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
</div>
```

To vertically align text in a `div` you should set the `line-height` of the div equal to its height, and to horizontally align `absolute` elements you should set its `left` and `right` to zero with `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
#custom{
  width: 50%;
  background: #FF0000;
  z-index: 99999;
  transform-origin: center center;
  top: 10px; 
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7%;
}
```

I removed the position absolute stuff and the div was centered.  Added some padding to center the text vertically