# Div is not centered when setting the width to 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I center my div, it's not centered. It seems, that his left corner is right in the middle of the screen. How can I substract the half of my width to this, that my div gets centered correctly?

In my css I write `left: 50%` and this is the result:

[image]

are there any possibilities to center this div correctly?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33516464/4305494 .. this has been asked many times, please do some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transform: translateX(-50%)` will shift the element to the left 50% of it's own width. paired with `left: 50%`, it will center something on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

And to extend Michael Coker's answer:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Will shift the element horizontally and vertically by half of it's width/height.

Answer (score 0):

This is another logic which worked for me to align the div in center

```js
  var divWidth = $(".center").width();
  var rowWidth = $(".row").width();
  var a = (rowWidth - divWidth) / 2;
  $(".center").css("margin-left", a);
```

```css
.center {
  background-color: green;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <div class="center" style="width:50%">
    Hello World
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```