# how to separate a menu and menu tab content width in 'Ant Design'?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to have my menu width `<Col span={6} offset={8}>`  and my content `<Col span={10} offset={7}>`. How do I do that?

```
  <Row>
    <Col span={6} offset={8}>
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="2" >
      <TabPane tab="About" key="1"><About /></TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="My Projects" key="2"><MyProjects /></TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Contact" key="3"><Contact /></TabPane>
    </Tabs>
    </Col>
  </Row>
```

This code smashes everything in `span={6}`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is tricky.
When the `TabPane` component is rendered, it contains lots of divs. The idea is to pick the div corresponding to the tab nav bar and apply `ant-col-6` class to it. Upon inspecting, you can get the required classes.

Add the following line of code to your component:

```
let navBar = document.getElementsByClassName('ant-tabs-bar')[0];
navBar.className += ' ant-col-15';
console.log(navBar)
```

To know why `ant-col-15`, if you need a `span` of 6, you have to give 6/10 *24 = 15

See my pen: https://codepen.io/danegit/pen/XzbLWL
Play with it until u get expected result

Comment: thanks for this. Is there a way to make these menu tabs to be centred? now everything goes from the left. :)

Comment: CSS buddy, CSS.. there are so many ways to horizontally center a `div`, like `margin: auto`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css