# Javascript: How to center multiple buttons that were created in Javascript using dynamically set CSS Style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a row of three buttons in Javascript using dynamically set CSS Style, but I am having difficulty trying to center the row of buttons in the middle of the page. This is with buttons that are currently not part of a div.

I have tried **button.align = 'center';** with no success.

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1856wzt5/) snippet.

HTML SKELETON

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Buttons</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script>
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var one, two, three;

function button(text) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var buttonText = document.createTextNode(text);
  button.appendChild(buttonText);
  return button;

}

function buttonTest() {
  one = button('one');
  two = button('two');
  three = button('three');

  // put the buttons on page
  document.body.appendChild(one);
  document.body.appendChild(two);
  document.body.appendChild(three);

}

buttonTest();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you easily horizontally center a <div> using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618097/how-do-you-easily-horizontally-center-a-div-using-css)

Comment: You need to wrap the buttons in a container. Use `text-align: center` in the container and you're done.

Comment: Andre Dion, I have looked at that post before, but it wasn't clear how to do this via dynamically set CSS Styling.

Answer (score 1):

[Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1856wzt5/2/)

```
var one, two, three;

function button(text) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var buttonText = document.createTextNode(text);
  button.appendChild(buttonText);
  return button;

}

function buttonTest() {
  one = button('one');
  two = button('two');
  three = button('three');

  var divElem = document.createElement('div');
  divElem.setAttribute('style', 'text-align:center;');
  // put the buttons on page
  //document.body.appendChild(one);
  //document.body.appendChild(two);
  //document.body.appendChild(three);
  divElem.appendChild(one);
  divElem.appendChild(two);
  divElem.appendChild(three);
    document.body.appendChild(divElem);
}

buttonTest();
```

Comment: Nice solution. You should explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be adding `text-align : center` to the `body`

```js
var one, two, three;

function button(text) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var buttonText = document.createTextNode(text);
  button.appendChild(buttonText);
  return button;

}

function buttonTest() {
  one = button('one');
  two = button('two');
  three = button('three');

  // put the buttons on page
  document.body.appendChild(one);
  document.body.appendChild(two);
  document.body.appendChild(three);

}

buttonTest();
```

```css
body {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Buttons</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```