# Send .txt folder from path HTML

Tags: html, sendmail

I have this codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="Cyan">
        <center>
            <a href="mailto:youremail@example.com?subject=ErrorLog&body=">Click me to send your log errors to developer.</a>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

The log file is located at `C:\Users\aimst\AppData\Local\log.txt`.

Also I want to Hide this:

[image]

Thanks for help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not possible with pure html.** Html only offers you a shortcut to sending an email yourself as a user. This is like **giving an email template** for users. I think you want to send an email from your server to a knwon adress. So "the website" sends a filled email. For this you need any kind of server-side programming because the server sends the email, not a user via his mail server.

PS: Note that the html tags [`center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and the attribute [`bgcolor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) both are deprecated. Use CSS for both. The `background` property replaces the `bgcolor` attribute. Centering elements is a little bit more tricky but one solution is using `flex` layout. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32007922/5934316) shows an example and also other possibilities how to center an element. (In my opinion `flex` is the best solution because is supported in most of the browsers now and it is not any kind of workaround but the intendet functionality.)

---

Because I know php here is an example code in php. This is also possible to write in any other language like python, java, javascript, ...

Html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="sendmail.php">
            <input type="submit" value="Send your log errors to developer." />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file style.css

```css
body{
    background: cyan;
}

form{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
}
```

PHP `sendmail.php` file

```php
<?php
    $message = 
        "The following logs have been sent by a user:\n\n".
        file_get_contents("C:\Users\aimst\AppData\Local\log.txt");

    mail("yourname@example.com", "Error Logs", $message);
?>
```

Note that you need any php server running for this, for example [Apache XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/).